# How to get query plan information from Postgres into JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to capture the cost numbers from the query plan you get when you 'Explain' a query.  Is there any way to get at this data inside of a Java ResultSet(or similar object)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, just run it as a regular statement:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("explain analyze select * from foo");
while (rs.next())
{
   System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: I am examining the ResultSet object (rs) in my debugger and didnt see that anywhere.  Thanks for the easy answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer supplied above, I would suggest that you make use of the ability to format EXPLAIN plans as XML in PostgreSQL 9.0 and later.

EXPLAIN ( analyze on, format xml ) SELECT ...

This will give you explain output you can more easily work with in Java by manipulating it as XML.

Answer (score 0):

An other example with PreparedStatement, this time.

Like this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("EXPLAIN (ANALYZE true , VERBOSE true , BUFFERS true)" +
                "SELECT * FROM Table");

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```

Or with a bind parameter:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("EXPLAIN (ANALYZE true , VERBOSE true , BUFFERS true)" +
                "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE id = ?");

preparedStatement.setLong(1, 1);

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```