# How to get an explain analyze on a jdbc commit?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am using a postgres database, and I want to optimize my program's speed. I have auto commit set to false. How can I get an explain analyze on foo.commit()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8356983/1177031

Comment: I know how to do explain analyze with SQL statements. However, commit is not a SQL statement, which leads me to ask that question.

Comment: `commit` has no execution plan. `explain` applies only to select,update,insert,delete.

Comment: @user937897 Actually, strictly `COMMIT` *is* an SQL statement, it's just a utility statement that doesn't have a query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, because there is *no query plan* for a `COMMIT`, and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` only applies to planned queries.

If you want the *execution duration* for the `COMMIT`, you can time that client-side, or you can set `log_min_duration_statement` to `0` and `client_min_messages` to `log` then capture the logs the server sends you.

If you're attempting to find out why a commit is slow, you're better off looking into:

- checkpoint durations; see [`log_checkpoints`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CHECKPOINTS)
- `pg_test_fsync` results for the storage subsystem
- Whether there are any `DEFERRABLE` constraints and constraint triggers in use;
- Overall system write load