# How to optimize a query that searches a many-to-many table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have 3 tables:

```
table1:{id, uid}
table2:{id, uid}
table1_table2:{table1_id, table2_id}
```

I need to execute the following queries:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table1_table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table1_table2.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1_table2.table2_id
WHERE table1.uid = ? and table2.uid = ?
```

I have unique indices on `UUID` columns, so I expected the search to be fast. When I have an almost empty database, select takes 0 ms, when there are 50,000 records in table 1, 100 records in table 2 and 110,000 records in table1_table2, select takes 10 ms, which is a lot, because I have to make 400,000 queries. Can I have O(1) on select?

Now I'm using hibernate(spring data) and postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unique indices but have you updated statistics with [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-analyze.html) as well?

What type is used for UID column and what type are you feeding it with from Java?

Is there any difference, when you run it from Hibernate/Java and from Postgres console?

Run the query with "EXPLAIN", get the execution plan - from Java as well as from Postgres console, and observe any differences. See [How to get query plan information from Postgres into JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356550/how-to-get-query-plan-information-from-postgres-into-jdbc)